# Maximum of an array constituting a pandas dataframe cell

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe in which a column is formed by arrays. So every cell is an array.

Say there is a column A in dataframe df, such that

```
A = [ [1, 2, 3], 
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9], 
      ... ]
```

I want to operate in each array and get, e.g. the maximum of each array, and store it in another column.

In the example, I would like to obtain another column

```
B = [ 3, 
      6,  
      9, 
      ...]
```

I have tried these approaches so far, none of them giving what I want.

```
df['B'] = np.max(df['A']);#

df.applymap (lambda B: A.max())

df['B'] = df.applymap (lambda B: np.max(np.array(df['A'].tolist()),0))
```

How should I proceed? And is this the best way to have my dataframe organized?

Comment: Don't store arrays in a DataFrame.  Keep it as an array or make it tidy, and then aggregate from that.  Storing any column of dtype `object` is going to be a hassle in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `apply(max)`. It doesn't matter if the values are lists or `np.array`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]})
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(max)
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
           a  b
0  [1, 2, 3]  3
1  [4, 5, 6]  6
2  [7, 8, 9]  9
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now, what if I want it to be the maximum but below, say, 9? Or if I want to make a condition depending on other columns which also contain arrays?

Comment: @acb Not sure I follow

Comment: I mean, what if there is another column c, where there are other arrays, say c = [ [2,3,8], [5, 6, 3], [8, 9, 1]] and I want the maximum of each array in 'a' only if its corresponding value in c is above 3? and only if that maximum is lower or equal than 8? Which should give b = [ 3, 6, 8]

Comment: @acb Then just use `'c'` instead of `'a'`... Otherwise show an example of what you mean

Comment: I mean, what if there is another column c, where there are other arrays, say c = [ [2,3,8], [5, 6, 3], [8, 9, 1]] and I want the maximum of each array in 'a' only if its corresponding value in c is above 3? and only if that maximum is lower or equal than 8? Which should give b = [ 3, 6, 8]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way without apply:

```
df['B']=np.max(df['A'].values.tolist(),axis=1)
```

---

```
           A  B
0  [1, 2, 3]  3
1  [4, 5, 6]  6
2  [7, 8, 9]  9
```

Comment: what if I have another column c, say c = [ [2,3,8], [5, 6, 3], [8, 9, 1]] and I want the maximum of each array in 'a' only if its corresponding value in c is above one value, let's say 3? and only if the maximum value in 'a' is lower or equal than say 8? This should give b = [ 3, 6, 8]

Comment: @acb that is different from what was originally asked. Please open a new question describing the overall requirements